# How to store the data from a datatable in an array

Tags: c#, android, sql-server

I am retrieving the data from a database table[110 rows and 8 columns] using a webservice and I want to store all this data in an array so that I can view and access this data easily on my android application.

this is my code:

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Webservice for generating category wise report in xml")]
public string getCategoryWiseReport_2(string district)
{
    string s = null;
            string ofc_code=null;
            string ofc_desg=null;
            string ofc_name=null;
            string dep_name=null;
            string total_comp=null;
            string pending=null;
            string desposed=null;
            string interim=null;
            string defaulter=null;
            string arr[];
    var con = new SqlConnection("data source=xxxx;initial catalog=xyz;integrated security=true");
    StringBuilder JSON = new StringBuilder();
    con.Open();
    var cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "ReportSummery";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@district", district);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    ad.Fill(dt);

    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {

            ofc_code = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
            ofc_desg = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
            ofc_name = dt.Rows[i][2].ToString();
            dep_name = dt.Rows[i][3].ToString();
            total_comp = dt.Rows[i][4].ToString();
            pending = dt.Rows[i][5].ToString();
            desposed = dt.Rows[i][6].ToString();
            interim = dt.Rows[i][7].ToString();
            defaulter = dt.Rows[i][8].ToString();

    }
    return ofc_code + "," + ofc_desg + "," + ofc_name + "," + total_comp + "," + pending + "," + desposed + "," + interim + "," + defaulter;
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: I want to store in array....so store it in array. What is the problem? Good point to start learning about collections: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybcx56wz.aspx

Comment: `JSON` is mentioned and then ignored; are you meant to be returning JSON here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're kinda doing this the hard way. Firstly, if you don't want the table in a `DataTable`: *don't use a `DataTable`*. You mention JSON in the code, so I'm going to assume this is meant to be idiomatic JSON; in which case - use a POCO:

```
class CategoryWiseRow {
    public string ofc_code {get;set;}
    public string ofc_desg {get;set;}
    public string ofc_name {get;set;}
    public string dep_name {get;set;}
    public string total_comp {get;set;}
    public string pending {get;set;}
    public string desposed {get;set;}
    public string interim {get;set;}
    public string defaulter {get;set;}
}
```

Then populate the data from the sproc - something like "dapper" would really help here:

```
List<CategoryWiseRow> data;
using(var con = new SqlConnection(....))
{
    data = con.Query<CategoryWiseRow>("ReportSummery", new { district },
        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
}
```

and use whatever JSON tool you prefer - for example Json.NET:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```